# Axis Multiplier near middle-axis

Tags: pgfplots

In PGFPlots I would like to have the multiplier for the specific axis near this axis when the axis is in the middle. The option `xlabel near ticks` does that, but moves the axis-label to the center of the plot.

I would prefer to have the multiplier and the axis label at the right end of the axis.
I couldn't find a solution in the pgfplots manual.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
                    width=0.8\textwidth,%
                    legend style={%
                    at={(0,0.5)},
                    anchor=south west },%
                    title={\bfseries Plot},%
                    axis x line=middle,%
                    axis y line=middle,%
                    minor tick num=9,%
                    xlabel=X-Axis,%
                    ylabel=Y-Axis ,%
                    scaled x ticks=base 10:3,%
                    %xlabel near ticks,%
                ]

                \addplot [domain=-0.03:0.03, mark=none, thick,blue,] 
                {10000*x + 50};

                \legend{Line}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just asked a little to early. If you set \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} the problem is solved. Stupid me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have already noticed, using `compat=1.9` moves the multiplier automatically. However, you can use the `every x tick scale label` style, in case finer control is needed (or an older version of  pgfplots` is installed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every x tick scale label/.style={
  at={(axis description cs:1,0.5)},yshift=-4em,inner sep=0pt,left
 }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
                    width=0.8\textwidth,%
                    legend style={%
                    at={(0,0.5)},
                    anchor=south west },%
                    title={\bfseries Plot},%
                    axis x line=middle,%
                    axis y line=middle,%
                    minor tick num=9,%
                    xlabel=X-Axis,%
                    ylabel=Y-Axis ,%
                    scaled x ticks=base 10:3,%
                    %xlabel near ticks,%
                ]

                \addplot [domain=-0.03:0.03, mark=none, thick,blue,] 
                {10000*x + 50};

                \legend{Line}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The default definition for the style:

```
/pgfplots/every x tick scale label/.style={
  at={(1,0)},yshift=-2em,left,inner sep=0pt
}
```